# How does getClass().getName() return class name of the generic type?

Tags: java, reflection

I know java uses type erasure for generics and java documentation says `getClass()` returns runtime class of the object, yet following program prints class name of the generic type. 
code:

```
    public class Gen<T> {
        T ob;
        public Gen(T ob) {
            this.ob=ob;
        }
        void showType() {
            System.out.println("Type of T is "+ ob.getClass().getName());

        }

}


    public class GenDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Gen<String> str = new Gen("abcd");
            str.showType();

        }

    }
```

output:
 `Type of T is java.lang.String`

 How does this program work? How is it getting runtime class of the non-reifiable type?
 EDIT

```
    public class Gen<T> {
        T ob;
        T ob1=ob;
        public Gen(T ob) {
            this.ob=ob;
        }
        void showType() {
            System.out.println("Type of T is "+ ob.getClass().getName());

        }
        void showType1(){
            System.out.println(ob1.getClass().getName());
        }

    }
public class GenDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gen<String> str = new Gen("abcd");
        str.showType();
        str.showType1();

    }

}
```

```
output:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Gen.showType1(Gen.java:13)
        at GenDemo.main(GenDemo.java:7)
```

Why same method call on `ob1` doesn't work?

Comment: Because `ob` refers to an object, which in turn carries around its own runtime type information.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If i create another variable T ob1=ob;, new variable refers to the same object which carries its own runtime type information right? Then  why calling getClass() on it causes NullPointer Exception?

Comment: @Arjun - Can you add a concrete example of this to your question?

Comment: @lexicore - Done.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have edited the question

Comment: Because `ob` is `null` at the point that you assign it to `ob1`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I get it now, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj` refers to an actual object (of type `String`).  At runtime, non-primitive objects carry around their type information with them, which is what `getClass()` returns.

This isn't really affected by generics (not least because generics don't exist at runtime).  It's exactly the same as if you'd done something like this:

```
Object ob = "abcd";
System.out.println(ob.getClass().getName());
```